# Regarding the triviality of the canonical line bundle $E(\gamma^1_2)$ for $\mathbb{RP}^2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles

I know that $E(\gamma^1_n)$ is non-trivial, but when I try to find local trivializations, I am finding that the transition functions are the identity, rendering the bundle trivial. I am obviously doing something wrong here.

Can anyone point out the wrong step for me. The reasoning goes:

Let $\tilde{U}_i$ be the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ with $x_i>0$.
Let $U_i$ be its image in $\mathbb{RP^2}$.
Let $p:E(\gamma_2^1)\rightarrow \mathbb{RP}^2$ be the canonical vector bundle.
Define $h_i: p^{-1}(U_i)\rightarrow U_i \times \mathbb{R}$ as $h_i([x],v) = ([x],v \cdot x)$.
This is obviously a homeomorphism with continuous inverse: $h_i^{-1} ([x],t) = ([x],tx)$.
Then the transition functions $t_{ij}$ on $U_i \cap U_j$ are the identity since $h_i$ does not depend on $U_i$.

This implies the bundle is trivial. Since it is not, what did I do wrong?

Comment: What does the notation $E(\gamma^1_2)$ mean?

Comment: Canonical line bundle on a projective space, is the line bundle where the fibre over the class of a line is the line.

Comment: Your maps $h_i$ are not well-defined. Compare $h_i([x], v)$ with $h_i([2x], v)$.

Comment: @KentaS $E(\gamma^1_n)$ is the subspace of $\mathbb{RP}^n \times \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ consisting of pairs $([x],v)$ for all $v \in [x]$

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese I was unclear, sorry. The map is $h_i ([x],v) = ([x], v \cdot \frac{x}{|x|})$. And similarly for $h_i^{-1}$.

Comment: That is still not well-defined. If $[x] = [x']$, the numbers $v\cdot \frac{x}{|x|}$ and $v\cdot\frac{x'}{|x'|}$ may be different.

Comment: Yeah, your right they can differ by a minus sign. Fair enough. Thanks.